# Android - Custom view and canvas size - Chicken and egg prob

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm designing a custom view that displays an expression (You can think about it as a complex TextView).

As the expression grows, I want my custom view to expand to accommodate it (Just like a wrap_content TextView).

when the content of the view is changed I buffer a canvas that is later drawn by `onDraw()`

The buffering is done using

```
Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height , Config.RGB);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
canvas.drawText(pos,text, paint);
pos += paint.MesureText(text);
// and so on...
...
...
```

Only at the end of this process I know what width of canvas I really need - The value of `pos`, but I need it prior to it's calculation in the `Bitmap.createBitmap()`.
Is there a way to create a canvas without specifies it's boundaries and then cut it to the right size? I don't want to do the process first to find out which width I need and then run it again to create an a view in the right size.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Views`'s `onSizeChanged` callback to create and populate the buffer.

This provides a good balance between eagerly buffering the data and deferring it to only when the view has a proper size.